# Parsing Json using Resources in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular controller and resource. I need to extract the Count and Items out my json feed. But get the following error:

Error: a.push is not a function

My Questions?

1) why can i not bind

```
$scope.items = data.Items;
```

2) why can i not get data.Count

```
var url = "http://www.cotw.local/api/journey/GetList";


ngMongo.factory("Mongo", function($resource) {
    return {
        database: $resource(url)
    };
});


ngMongo.controller("CurrentCtrl", function ($scope, Mongo) {

    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        Mongo.database.query({'journeyStatusId': '', 'page': $scope.currentPage }, function (data) {

            /* i need to get the count here */
             console.log(data.Count);
        $scope.items = data.Items;
        }, function (error) {
            // error handler
        });
    };

    $scope.$watch('currentPage', $scope.setPage);
});
```

My json

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "FirstName": null,
            "LastName": null,
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "OutletId": null,
            "JourneyStatusId": null,
            "Disable": false,
            "Created": "2014-04-29T14:19:14",
            "Modified": "2014-04-29T14:19:14"
        }
    ],
    "Count": 1
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you get when you do console.log(data) after the query?

Comment: Remove `isArray = true,` and try. The config is provided when you create resource.

Comment: I've updated my code, and shown the firebug response

Comment: @Chandermani your right? i needed set isArray = false

Comment: @Chandermani - feel free to answer if you'd like the points :)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the response was a object and providing IsArray true makes Angular think the response as is an array and de-serialize fails.

Setting `isArray=false` works.